# VW Golf Mark IV (2004) low acceleration with pedal maxed

Tags: vw, golf

My Golf just had its oxygen sensors replaced (Check Engine Light came on about a month ago, I didn't have the time/money to replace it until now). However, in the past week or two, it has completely lost whatever oomph it had beforehand. To the point where, when I ordinarily shift into third gear, I can drop the pedal to the floor and get an absolutely tepid response. This into fourth and fifth gear. The car *does* accelerate, but at an asthmatic pace it didn't have beforehand.

Is it the clutch? Please tell me it's not the clutch.

Comment: Which engine does this have in it (I'd bet it's the 1.8T, but just making sure)?

Comment: Nope, 2.0, no trim, most basic of models.

Comment: well, if your revs are not getting high while you try to accelerate, I mean they match with the speed you are running then it is not the clutch... I'm not an expert with VW electronics but might be ECU related issue and more specifically a safe mode on the ECU. Certainly it worth some investigation since you experience low performance and in order to avoid a bigger damage. My best advice at this point is to take the car in a garage to check the ECU for error codes and share those with us in order to help you further.

Comment: My spidey sense is tingling about exhaust backpressure.  But there's very little information here; any codes or live data would be helpful on this quite broad problem.